# Listener in Jmeter to listen the message generated from signalr

Tags: jmeter, signalr

Can anyone suggest me a listener in Jmeter in order to listen the message from Signalr in Json format?

I am using apache-jmeter-3.1 version.

Comment: if I understand correctly, it's using WebSockets, so look at WebSocket Sampler: https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler

Comment: I believe that for Signalr 2.x you have to have a client to receive messages from a SignalR server.